# Set column's default display to hexadecimal format

Tags: mysql, sql, formatting, hex, mariadb

I'm looking for way to create a MySQL column where a `SELECT` statement will automatically display any value formatted as hexadecimal:

```
1  -> 0x1
16 -> 0x10
```

Here is an example that achieved basically this result, but the problem is that any user of this data will have to do the processing (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3bc633/2):

**Create data:**

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  c1 int
);

INSERT INTO t1 (c1) VALUES
  (0x1),
  (0x10);
```

**Select the data:**

```
SELECT c1, CONCAT('0x', HEX(c1))
FROM t1;
```

I would like to set a property on the column or table, to achieve this result with a simple `SELECT c1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  c1 int,
  c2 varchar(32) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CONCAT('0x', HEX(c1)))
);

MariaDB [test]> INSERT INTO t1 (c1) VALUES
    ->   (0x1),
    ->   (0x10);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.14 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [test]> select * from t1;
+------+------+
| c1   | c2   |
+------+------+
|    1 | 0x1  |
|   16 | 0x10 |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Or, if you use an older version, it will probably be

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  c1 int,
  c2 varchar(32) AS (CONCAT('0x', HEX(c1))) VIRTUAL
);
```

But the same principle apply.